# Terminated the 'mysqld' process in Amazon Linux - everything appears to work, or does it?

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, amazon-ec2

So I noticed that the 'mysqld' process on my Amazon Linux machine (EC2 Instance) was hogging a ton of memory. I terminated it and it instantly resolved this issue. I have separate RDS databases and I can still access and transmit information to these over the web via my host with no issues whatsoever. I assume other processes help handle this.

So my question is: Although everything appears to work on the front end web pages, what's the downside to not having this process running? I noticed that there are other databases labeled "information_schema" and "mysql" that have data being written which are modified very frequently, but I didn't create these DBs and they aren't application critical.

So is this process just storing server information into those DBs? Will having this off cause more chaos than it's worth?

**EDIT:** I've discovered that the information being stored into the databases is all coming from functions in the RDS service, NOT the linux host. So the assumption still stands that if I am not running queries into 'localhost' then I don't need this process at all. I only directly communicate with Amazon RDS.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You really need to develop a more thorough understanding of what's going on here.  You shouldn't have something running, consuming a lot of memory, for absolutely no reason.  Most of the memory use of `mysqld` is unrelated to the amount of work being done -- it allocates memory primarily based on configuration, not actual workload -- so this really should not be a case of "it wasn't doing anything.'

Answer (score -1):

`information_schema` is very-much application-critical! In Unix and Unix-like systems, processes ending with "d" are daemons (c.f. "services" in Windows) and cannot be terminated at will without something happening. I do not have enough information to know the in-depth architecture of your application but I suggest you notice no front-end issue due to some form of database replication in place on your backend. Suggestions:

From Wikipedia:

> Information schema is ... a set of read-only views which provide information about all of the tables, views, columns, and procedures in a database

Without this your data loses its structure. You also cannot get rid of, or ignore, the `mysql` table - it stores core things liek your users... try run `select user, host from mysql.user;` to see what I mean.

1. Look at your general query log to understand what's causing MySQL to consume significant memory - possible reasons are inefficient `join` operations, long queries and wildcard (`%`) operators being used too liberally. THis will give you some place to start
2. Run a `service mysql restart` as a root user (use `sudo` or `su` to achieve this if needed)
3. Monitor the entire `mysqld` process tree with `htop`, a great tool to supplement the standard `top` command that ships with many Unix-like systems

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown here. I made an edit to the end of the question in hopes of clearing up my intentions on the service usage.

Answer (score -1):

If it's your box, you should know whether you need it or not.

If you need it and it's using too much memory, then [tell it to use less.](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/03/best-practices-for-configuring-optimal-mysql-memory-usage/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning towards that I don't actually need it anymore. I initially set up mysql on this box because I thought it was required to allow PHP to do any kind of communication to remote databases, but I can see how this is not the case.